# How can I use the email instead of the username in LDAP authentication with PHP?

Tags: php, active-directory, ldap

Currently, I am able to login using the username and password. I wish to be able to login using email address instead of the username. How do you suggest I do it?
Script:

```
$ldap['username'] = "domain\user123";
$ldap['password'] = "password123";
$ldap['host']   = 'site.domain.com';
$ldap['port']   = 389;
$ldap['dn'] = "CN=Users, DC=domain, DC=com";

$ldap['conn'] = ldap_connect( $ldap['host'], $ldap['port'] )
or die("Could not connect to {$ldap['host']}" );

$ldap['bind'] = ldap_bind($ldap['conn'], $ldap['username'], $ldap['password']);

if( !$ldap['bind'] )
{
echo "Failed";
}

else if( $ldap['bind'] )
{
echo "Success";
}
```

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Thanks so much!

Comment: Hello! But I can't bind using email. So how can I proceed with the search? Is it ok if I search first before binding it?

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question (thought you were SEARCHING instead of binding). You can't bind without your username as far as I know - it has to be a username and pass.

Comment: Oh no..Really?!.. oh well, thanks for the info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to bind with a user with read-access to the LDAP-server, search for the DN of the user with the email-address in question and then use that DN to do a second bind. If the second bind is successful the user is logged in, if the second bind fails, the login fails.

I've created a gist showing that process at https://gist.github.com/heiglandreas/5689592

Answer (score 3):

Not the email Address, unless it is the same as the userPrincipalName.

When using Microsoft Active Directory, you can bind with the userprincipal name, samAccountName (typically you need domain\samAccountName) and of course the DN.

Comment: you might not be able to use the email-address directly but you csn use the email-address to look for the DN or the sAMAccountName and use that then. And I'ce seen sAMAccountName@domain also working but that might habe been configured accordingly by the admins

Comment: It is NOT samAccountName. The name@domainName is the userPrincipalName.

Comment: I'd say that depends on configuration. i've seen sAMAccountName@domain being used as userPrincipalName and therefore the userPrincipalName is equal to the email-adress. But I might have seen a non-standard config there.